# 2 errors in my javascript random number-guessing game

Tags: javascript

This is the first app I have ever written.  I have seen a million random number-generating games here, javascript and otherwise, but none had the problems I'm having.  I apologize for my ignorance, but when I know what I'm doing wrong, this will go a long way toward my understanding of javascript and coding in general. I'm just playing in the browser console as of now.

I've done this with a for loop, but I wanted to try another option and use a decrement counter.  I've tried using the if/else stuff from the inner function inside the while loop.  The code looks right to me.

```
const guessingGame = (tries) => {
    const answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)
    let guess = null
    let status = "playing"
    function makeGuess() {
        if (guess === answer) {
            status = "won"
        } else if (tries === 0) {
            status = "lost"
        } else {
            tries--
            if (tries === 1) {
                console.log(tries + ' guess left')
            } else {
                console.log(tries + ' guesses left')
            }
        }
    }
    while (status === "playing") {
        if (!guess) {
            guess = prompt('Guess a number between 1 and 10')
            makeGuess()
        } else if (guess > answer) {
            guess = prompt('Lower')
            makeGuess()
        } else if (guess < answer) {
            guess = prompt('Higher')
            makeGuess()
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    console.log("Game Over.  You " + status + "!  The answer was " + answer + ".")
}
```

1. This game should invoke/launch with one argument, the number of tries allowed.  If I correctly guess the answer, the console log at the end should include status = "won".  But when I win, it includes status = "playing".
2. When I guess wrong "tries" number of times, I should lose.  But when I see "0 guesses left" in the console, the game gives one more guess, and I can take it, effectively making tries -1, I think.  When I make one additional wrong guess, status correctly changes to "lost" and the final console message is correct.

Comment: You checked `tries === 0` before `tries--`, that's why you get `0 guesses left`.

Comment: And the `guess` is actually a string not a number, so `guess === answer` never true. The next iteration after you guessed correctly, it falls into `else{break}` with the status still `playing`. You either want `Number(guess) === . answer` or just `guess == answer`.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, Ricky Mo.  Thanks much.  I fixed those 2 things and it's working exactly as I had imagined.  As Amadan said, my last attempt at fixing those 2 problems got pretty weird.  Now that I know what the 2 problems were, I'm going to re-structure/simplify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You checked `tries === 0` before `tries--`, that's why you get 0 guesses left. You should decrement before checking.
2. The guess is actually a string not a number, so `guess === answer` never true. The next iteration after you guessed correctly, it falls into `else{break}` with the `status` still playing. You either want `Number(guess) === answer` or just `guess == answer`.
3. By `Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)` you are actually generating 0-10. You want `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1` for 1-10. Just remember `Math.floor(Math.random() * n)` gives you `n` possible outcomes, which happens to be an integer in the range `[0,n)`. Then do whatever calculation you want to map it to your desire output value.

```js
const guessingGame = (tries) => {
    const answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    let guess = null
    let status = "playing"
    function makeGuess() {
        tries--;
        if (guess === answer) {
            status = "won"
        } else if (tries === 0) {
            status = "lost"
        } else {
            
            if (tries === 1) {
                console.log(tries + ' guess left')
            } else {
                console.log(tries + ' guesses left')
            }
        }
    }
    while (status === "playing") {
        if (!guess) {
            guess = Number(prompt('Guess a number between 1 and 10'))
            makeGuess()
        } else if (guess > answer) {
            guess = Number(prompt('Lower'))
            makeGuess()
        } else if (guess < answer) {
            guess = Number(prompt('Higher'))
            makeGuess()
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    console.log("Game Over.  You " + status + "!  The answer was " + answer + ".")
}
guessingGame(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `prompt` is a string; thus, `guess` is a string. The result of `Math.floor` is a number, so `answer` is a number.

`>` and `<` are coercing operators: if one of the operands is a number, the other is converted into the number, as well. This means `guess < answer` and `guess > answer` work as you hope it does.

However, you've apparently heard people say "never use `==`, always use `===`" and taken it to heart. The reason for the saying is `==` is also a coercing operator, and as a consequence sometimes things that don't look equal end up being equal. However, here you actually needed to use the coercing `==`, because `1 == '1'` (even though `1` and `'1'` are different types), but the strict `1 === '1'` ends up being `false`!

Thus, you first check if `guess` is strictly equal to `answer`. Since their types are different, it is impossible, so you move on. You check if `guess` is above the answer, then you check whether it is below the `answer`, both of those return `false` as well. The only remaining option is to `break` from the loop - and `"winner"` never gets printed.

---

Beside this, your biggest problem is actually logic. The placement of different tests and actions is somewhat questionable. For example, one would expect that testing whether `guess` is equal to the `answer` would be right next to the test to see if it is bigger or smaller. The test for `tries` would be most at home right at the `while` loop; but you have an infinite loop, and an independent test for `tries`. You enter the first guess with a unique prompt, but it is inside an infinite loop, despite the fact it can only ever happen once. You have a function called `makeGuess`, but the function does two or three different things, none of which is actually making a guess.

Rather than start working on code right away, then fixing problems as they pop up, try to imagine first what the flow would be. How would a human do it? *Then* write code.

---

Here's the basic idea for the same game:

```
answer = imagineAnswer()
guess = askForFirstGuess()
status = "lost"
while (--tries) {
  if (guess > answer) {
    guess = askForHigherGuess()
  } else if (guess < answer) {
    guess = askForLowerGuess()
  } else {
    status = "won"
    break
  }
}
reportGameEnd(status)
```

Comment: Gotcha Amadan.  Thanks for your time.  I tried this many different ways much closer to what you suggest, but I kept having the 2 problems, so I kept trying different ideas.  This was the most recent, final try before asking for help.